# I speak but do not listen

Tags: riddle

I think this one will be easy.

> I speak but do not listen
>
> I am round but not a circle
>
> I am soft to your ears
>
> I really like to sing
>
> I have a friend that listens but does not speak

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think:

> Headphones and / or headsets

I speak but do not listen

> You can listen to them but they don't listen to you

I am round but not a circle

> Most headphones have round cups for the ears

I am soft to your ears

> Well obviously the cups are soft to your ears or you'd never wear them (for long)

I really like to sing

> Most people use them for music

I have a friend that listens but does not speak

> Some headphones have a microphone and at least headsets do have a microphone

Comment: >! try plugging headphones into the microphone jack some time,  if you shout it will pick it up.

Comment: @Jasen Yes, that is true, though that is not the way it's meant to be operated :P

Answer (score 4):

is it, given that you didn't expect it to last long:

> mouth

I speak but do not listen

> mouth speaks, but cannot hear, obviously

I am round but not a circle

> mouth is round, but obviously is not a circle, just an opening on the face

I am soft to your ears

> people "Like the sound of their own voice"

I really like to sing

> a lot of people sing, and all sing with mouth

I have a friend that listens but does not speak

> the face also houses the ears

Answer (score 3):

You might be:

> Earpods

I speak but do not listen

> Earpods produce sound but do not listen like a mic does

I am round but not a circle

> They are round

I am soft to your ears

> Usually they are softened with soft materials

I really like to sing

> People use them to listen to music

I have a friend that listens but does not speak

> A microphone

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you're a:

> Robin bird

I speak but do not listen

> To us, a bird is not listening

I am round but not a circle

> Round robin

I am soft to your ears

> A robin's song is sweet

I really like to sing

> It seems all robins do is sing

I have a friend that listens but does not speak

> Us, we listen but don't speak to the robin.